# Grouping of data in select input. CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Firstly, sorry for my English.

I would like to create a select input in CakePHP, who will have grouped the data.

Let's suppose I have some news in categories, I want to display it in the select input, that they are grouped by category, something like this:

---

== first category == (not clickable)

1 news of the first category

2 news of the first category

3 news of the first category

== Second category == (not clickable)

1 news of the second category

2 news of the second category

3 news of the second category

== third category == (not clickable)

[...]

etc.

---

Controller:

```
$this->set('news', $this->News->find('all',
array(
    'CONTAIN' => array('News' => array('Category'))
    'fields' => array('News.name', 'Category.name')
)));
```

View:

```
echo $this->form->input('news', array('options' => $news));
```

I have no idea how to create so grouped in a list. I tried using a parameter group, but nothing came.
At the moment it seems to me that would be some way to modify the `$news` as `$options` before displaying it in a view, but probably  it is not the best solution.

I wonder whether there is possible to create appropriately grouped array in `$news` in the controller, or remain modification array before being displayed in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Have you define relation between Category and news in model?.
if you have define relation than you will get data like

[0] => Array
        (
            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [Category_name] => Frist Category

```
            )

        [News] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [Category_id] => 1
                        [news] => first news

                     )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [Category_id] => 1
                        [news] => second news

                     )
            )
 )
```

So you can loop easily.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer!

It turned out that I missed the showParents parameter in the view:

```
echo $this->Form->input('news', array('options'=>$news, 'showParents'=>true));
```

It helped me to group my list and now I'm on good way.